# Please help me write a mysql query to select members of a particular department

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 2 tables, `employee` and `department`, `department` has 2 departments, dpt1 and dpt2, and there are 12 employees, 6 is each department, and 4 belonging to both departments. How can I use a mysql query to find those employees who belong only to dpt2 and not dpt1?

Comment: How you design connection between employee and department, do you have separate table with many to many relations, or just field in employee with "dep1,dept2" value ?

Comment: A field with dept1,dept2 value....

Comment: not too wise... are you consider changes ?

Comment: Actually this was the exact question I was asked by my teacher....so I am looking for the best answer specific to that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT employee.*
FROM employee
INNER JOIN employee_belongs_to_departments
WHERE employee.id = employee_belongs_to_departments.employee_id
AND employee_belongs_to_departments.department_id = 'dpt2'
AND employee.id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ebtd2.employee_id
  FROM employee_belongs_to_departments ebtd2
  WHERE ebtd2.employee_id = employee.id
  AND ebtd2.department_id = 'dpt1'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach in this kind of situation would be to have a third "connection" table, called something like `employeeDepartment`.

```
CREATE TABLE employeeDepartment (
    employee INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    department INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (employee, department)
)
```

and then you also make `employee` and `department` foreign keys to the primary keys of the appropriate tables, though this requires you to be using the right storage engine (not that that is hard to do).

This makes doing various things a whole lot easier than the approach you seem to be going for (storing a list of values in one column).

You could then use

```
SELECT
    eD1.employee
FROM
    employeeDepartment AS eD1
    LEFT JOIN employeeDepartment AS eD2 ON
        eD1.employee = eD2.employee AND
        eD2.department = 'dpt2' -- replace with appropriate integer
                                -- if using integers as I suggested
WHERE
    eD1.department = 'dpt1' AND -- same comment applies
    eD2.employee IS NULL
```